# iOS application runs in the background mode by default

Tags: ios, xcode, runtime, debug-mode

Is there any way to make an iOS application starts running in the background under debug mode?

I mean, when you press Cmd+R - the app will be running, but you still need to tap an application icon on the device to open the app.

Comment: What I usually do in projects that require checking both is create two schemes, one for foreground and one for background, so I can quickly switch between them when I need to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. In Xcode in the top click your Apps name then click Edit Scheme... Then click Run on the left, then click the Options tab, half way down it will say Background Fetch, check that. Then when you run your app it will start in the background.

[Edit Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWKtx.png)